# Python: print data to new line after printing some data

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def printable(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            print(l[i][j])
        print()
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
printable(tableData)
```

For example if i have a data like

```
bob,sob,cob,dab
```

if i print it using loop then it will be printed one by one what i want is
after printing bob and sob i want the cursor come back upwards and then print cob dab

```
first:print  
      bob  
      sob  
second:then cursor comes back up and print  
      cob  
      dab              
the output i wanted is  
bob cob  
sob dab
```

if i remove dab in the above data then the output should be
bob cob
sob
Is this possible in Python?
can anyone provide an example

Comment: can you provide the expected output for some input ? your question does not match what you described and your code has animals, names and fruit not some 'dab sob cab' - it is confusing, but in general you cant return to a line after printing it - create a list of lines and print it after you have built it already

Comment: What operating system are you using? If on Unix you could use [**`curses`**](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)

Comment: If you really want to do it this way you can uses [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), but you should probably just restructure to print things in the correct order the first time

Comment: You can [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) sequences to iterate over them in consort.

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik the 'dab sab cab' is example i have taken if i have input like a,b,c,d when we print it using loop it prints one by one all i want is after printing a and b then c and d should print in the new line as i have shown in the above output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
        ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
        ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

for row in zip(*data):
    print(' '.join(row))
```

output

```
apples Alice dogs
oranges Bob cats
cherries Carol moose
banana David goose
```

EDIT - expand the answer in case of unequal length:
Use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
from itertools import zip_longest
data = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
['dogs', 'cats', 'moose']]

for row in zip_longest(*data, fillvalue=''):
    print(' '.join(row))
```

output

```
apples Alice dogs
oranges Bob cats
cherries Carol moose
banana David
```

The default fillvalue is `None` - you can keep it if you prefer

Comment: if i remove 'goose' then the last column is not printing how do i get output even if i remove one or two elements in list

Comment: what is not clear in the loop? Just check (e.g print) what zip/zip_longest return.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on one of the answers and using your simple list (bob, sob, cob, dab), you can use a modulo based on index position in the single-dimension list, then append '\n' to create a new line with proper spacing:

```
data = ['bob','sob','cob','dab']
print(' '.join(['\n{}'.format(i) if data.index(i) % 2 == 0 else i for i in data]))
```

Output:

```
bob sob 
cob dab
```

Comment: can u explain above print statement

Comment: @CvNikhil Without the print statement, the output would end up having the '\n' in it (`'\nbob sob \ncob dab'`). Printing those puts data on new lines so that output is formatted per your request.  Dies that answer your question or are you referring to something else?